# Category and Posts in front page

Tags: posts, categories, frontpage

i would like to make a front page with the category name and under every post of the category.The code that i have tried is:

```
$categories_list = get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ', ', ' ' ) );
if ( $categories_list ) {

    /* translators: 1: list of categories. */
    printf( '<span class="cat-links">' . esc_html__( 'Posted in %1$s', 'plavou_2017' ) . '</span>', $categories_list ); // WPCS: XSS OK.
}

            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            $args = array(
  'exclude' => '',
    'feed' => '',
);

wp_list_categories( $args );


                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;

            the_posts_navigation();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif; ?>
```

It works at one point, but i would prefer for having the categories print again for each category, better have the category and the post of it.Now it prints all the categories again for every post.

Comment: You should describe the problem you have to do it by yourself, at least what you have tried or investigated; just dumping what you want to do is out of the scope of this site. Please, see how the [asking section of the Help Center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't require to hesitate your self as beginner in wordpress.
Second, for category listing with according posts you need to do something like below:

```
     <ul class="et_pb_tabs_controls clearfix tab-ul">
                            <?php 
                            dynamic_sidebar('sidebar');    
                            $cate_id=get_query_var('cat');

                            global $sitepress;

                            $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

                            $sitepress->switch_lang( $sitepress->get_default_language() );

                            $args = array(
                                'type'                     => 'post',
                                'child_of'                 => 0,
                                'parent'                   => '',
                                'orderby'                  => 'name',
                                'order'                    => 'DESC',
                                'hide_empty'               => 1,
                                'hierarchical'             => 1,
                                'exclude'                  => 1,
                                'include'                  => '',
                                'number'                   => '',
                                'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
                                'pad_counts'               => false 
                                );
                            $flag=0;        
                            $inc=0;

                            foreach (get_categories( $args ) as $category):
                               $flag=($inc==0)?0:1;   
                           if( !is_array($cate_id) && $cate_id=="")
                               $category_arr[]= $category->term_id;   

                           ?>
                           <li class="et_pb_tab_0 <?php echo ($flag==0)? 'et_pb_tab_active':'';?>"><a href="#<?php echo $category->name; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
                           <?php 
                           $inc++; 
                           endforeach; ?>
                       </ul>
<?php foreach ($category_arr as $category_id):
                            $arr=array(
                                'post_type' => 'post',
                                'order'=>"ASC",
                                'cat'=>$category_id,
                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                'paged' => $current_page,
                                'suppress_filters' => false
                                );
                        $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query($arr); ?>
<div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_1 full-width">
    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : 
    $increment=0;
    while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : 

        if(($increment%3)==0){
            echo '</div><div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_1 full-width">';
        }
        $wpb_all_query->the_post(); 

        ?>
        <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3 et_pb_column_1">
            <div class="et_pb_posts et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_blog_0">
                <div class="entry box">
                    <!--If no results are found-->
                    <?php $post_link=  get_permalink(); ?>
                    <?php $img_path=get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id()); ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $post_link;?>">

                      <?php  if($url !=""){
                        ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="">
                        <?php } ?>
                    </a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $post_link;?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
                    <p class="box-content"><?php echo(get_the_excerpt()); ?></p>
                    <div class="profile-box"> 
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/profile-icon.png" alt="" id="" data-height-percentage="54" data-actual-width="18" data-actual-height="28">  
                        <div class="pro-name"><h4><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></h4>                                   
                            <span><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--End if no results are found-->
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_posts -->
        </div><!-- .et_pb_column -->
        <?php 
        $increment++;
        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata();
        endif; 
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have maybe some reference material?

Comment: I add just a foreach loop withe post loop inside